# Write AVRO from spark-shell in Spark 2.4

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, avro

Spark 2.4.0 on Java 1.8.0_161 (Scala 2.11.12)

Run command: `spark-shell --jars=spark-avro_2.11-2.4.0.jar`

Currently working on some POC using small avro files, I want to be able to read in a (single) AVRO file, make a change, then write it back out.

Reading is fine:
`val myAv = spark.read.format("avro").load("myAvFile.avro")`

However, I am getting this error when trying to write back out (even before making any changes):

```
scala> myAv.write.format("avro").save("./output-av-file.avro")

org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException:
Datasource does not support writing empty or nested empty schemas.
Please make sure the data schema has at least one or more column(s).
         ;
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$DataSource$$validateSchema(DataSource.scala:733)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.planForWriting(DataSource.scala:523)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveToV1Source(DataFrameWriter.scala:281)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:270)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:228)
  ... 49 elided
```

I've tried specifying the schema of the dataframe manually, but to no avail:
`.write.option("avroSchema", c_schema.toString).format("avro") ...`

Answer (score 0):

Reason is quite obvious schema is coming as empty. [see here from code](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/datasources/DataSource.scala#L775)

```
if (hasEmptySchema(schema)) {
      throw new AnalysisException(
        s"""
           |Datasource does not support writing empty or nested empty schemas.
           |Please make sure the data schema has at least one or more column(s).
         """.stripMargin)
    }
```